# How to sort all tags on StackOverflow according to number of question?

Tags: support, tags, sorting

Is this possible to show all tags of StackOverflow sorted according to number of questions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular

Comment: Why there are down votes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is how they are sorted by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that. This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/340349/tags-and-the-number-of-questions-sorted-desc) does show the tags and the number of questions those tags are used on.

```
select t.tagname
     , count(*) [number of questions]
from tags t
inner join posttags pt on pt.tagid = t.id
inner join posts p on p.id = pt.postid
group by t.tagname
order by count(*) desc
```

but the [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page is ordered in the same manner (from left to right, row by row)

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular also shows tags sorted according to number of question. As @PolyGeo suggested

Comment: That is the default view of /tags....

Comment: Yes. I did not know about that link.